# PHP: Extending static member arrays

Tags: php, inheritance, static-members

I'm having the following scenario:

```
class A { public static $arr=array(1,2); }
class B extends A { public static $arr=array(3,4); }
```

Is there any way to combine these 2 arrays so `B::$arr` is `1,2,3,4`?

I don't need to alter these arrays, but I can't declare them als const, as PHP doesn't allow const arrays.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
The PHP manual states, that I can only assign strings and constants, so `parent::$arr + array(1,2)` won't work, but I think it should be possible to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct, you can only assign literals and constants when declaring a static variable. The work-around would be to assign the value in code just after the class is declared. In Java you could do this nicely with a static initialiser, but PHP doesn't support those either, so we have to define and call a method ourselves:

```
class A { public static $arr=array(1,2); }
class B extends A {
  public static $arr;
  public static function init() {
    self::$arr = array_merge(parent::$arr, array(3,4));
  }
}; B::init();
```

Also note the use of `array_merge` instead of the union (`+`) operator - the union operator won't combine the arrays as you intend, as they have identical numerical keys - the first is `array(0=>1, 1=>2)`, second is `array(0=>3, 1=>4)`; the union of them will only contain each key  once, so you'll either end up with `(1,2)` or `(3,4)` depending on the order you union them.

Comment: Doh, you beat me. Still I like my solution more since there isn't an init() dependancy.

Comment: I just used array(1,2) as an example, in the project it's an associative array so + would work.

Comment: Can't use `this` in static context. Try static/self.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to get a bit fancy as you won't be able to define a static variable.

```
<?php

class A 
{
    public static $arr = array(1, 2);
    public static function getArr(){ return self::$arr; }
}

class B extends A 
{
    public static $arr = array(3, 4);
    public static function getArr(){ return array_merge(parent::$arr, self::$arr); }
}


print_r( A::getArr() );
print_r( B::getArr() );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Also good since you can access the original arrays too:

```
print_r( A::$arr );
print_r( B::$arr );

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Comment: Also a good answer, but the arrays will be merged every time I want to access them and inheriting if from B should work, `getArr()` would have to call `parent::getArr()`, not `parent::$arr`.

Comment: True. I don't think inheritance and static properties make a lot of sense anyway. Whatever works though.